# Python Add Elements to Lists within List if Missing

Tags: python, list, pandas, numpy

Given the following list of lists:

```
a = [[2,3],[1,2,3],[1]]
```

I need each list within a to have the same number of elements.
First, I need to get the longest length of any list in a.
Then, I need to ensure all lists are at least that long.
If not, I want to add a zero (0) to the end until that is true. 
The desired result is:

```
b = [[2,3,0],[1,2,3],[1,0,0]]
```

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I also need to apply this to a Pandas Data Frame like this one:

```
import pandas as pd
b = [[2,3,0],[1,2,3],[1,0,0]]
f=pd.DataFrame({'column':b})
```

Comment: Can you post your attempts please?

Comment: Seems relevant : [`Convert Python sequence to NumPy array, filling missing values`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619143/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
pd.DataFrame(a).fillna(0)
```

[image]

---

to get exactly what you asked for

```
pd.Series(pd.DataFrame(a).fillna(0).astype(int).values.tolist()).to_frame('column')
```

[image]

---

this is also related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40569220/2336654)

where you can get much better performance with

```
def box(v):
    lens = np.array([len(item) for item in v])
    mask = lens[:,None] > np.arange(lens.max())
    out = np.full(mask.shape, 0, dtype=int)
    out[mask] = np.concatenate(v)
    return out

pd.DataFrame(dict(columns=box(a).tolist()))
```

[image]

---

***timing***
[image]

Comment: would be my goto solution

Answer (score 5):

First, compute the maximum length of your elements:

```
maxlen=len(max(a,key=len))  # max element using sublist len criterion
```

or as Patrick suggested do it using generator comprehension on sublist lengths, probably a tad faster:

```
maxlen=max(len(sublist) for sublist in a)  # max of all sublist lengths
```

then create a new list with 0 padding:

```
b = [sl+[0]*(maxlen-len(sl)) for sl in a]  # list comp for padding
```

result with `a = [[2,3],[1,2,3],[1]]`:

```
[[2, 3, 0], [1, 2, 3], [1, 0, 0]]
```

Note: could be done in one line but would not be very performant because of the recomputation of maxlen. One-liners are not always the best solution.

```
b = [sl+[0]*(len(max(a,key=len))-len(sl)) for sl in a]  # not very performant
```

Comment: `maxlen=len(max(a,key=len))` looks a little odd.  Any reason to do it this way over `maxlen=max(len(sublist) for sublist in a)`

Comment: no, it was just the most complicated one-liner I could think of :). I _know_ I have to avoid `filter`, `map` and a lot of complex constructs which are best replaced by listcomps/gencomps most of the time, but I continue doing so...  edited with your alternative.

Comment: I know what you mean.  I did nothing but functional programming for a few years and sometimes I feel like I've come back and am trying to tell everyone that it's all just shadows on a wall.

Comment: very philosophical :) I lost a good answer the other day over those functional artifacts. And in python 3 when you need a list from those you have to explicitly convert it, making it even more complex. That's decided: I'm stopping :) thanks for getting me out of the cave.

Comment: With `itertools.zip_longest` you don't need to figure out the max length yourself.

Comment: Yes but you have to transpose the data afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in a: 
    while len(i) < 3:
        i.append(0)
```

Comment: slow... avoid for-loops and most importantly appends :)

Comment: @JohnSmith Thank you for pointing that out, I actually wasn't aware especially regarding appends, that's good to know :)