# How to repeat a numpy array along a new dimension with padding?

Tags: python, numpy

Given an two arrays: an input array and a repeat array,  I would like to receive an array which is repeated along a new dimension a specified amount of times for each row and padded until the ending.

```py
to_repeat = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
repeats = np.array([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1])
# I want final array to look like the following:
#[[1, 0, 0],
# [2, 2, 0],
# [3, 3, 0],
# [4, 4, 4],
# [5, 5, 5],
# [6, 0, 0]]
```

The issue is that I'm operating with large datasets (10M or so) so a list comprehension is too slow - what is a fast way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one with `masking` based on [`this idea`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40571482/) -

```
m = repeats[:,None] > np.arange(repeats.max())
out = np.zeros(m.shape,dtype=to_repeat.dtype)
out[m] = np.repeat(to_repeat,repeats)
```

Sample output -

```
In [44]: out
Out[44]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 0],
       [3, 3, 0],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5],
       [6, 0, 0]])
```

Or with broadcasted-multiplication -

```
In [67]: m*to_repeat[:,None]
Out[67]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 0],
       [3, 3, 0],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5],
       [6, 0, 0]])
```

For large datasets/sizes, we can leverage `multi-cores` and be more efficient on memory with [`numexpr` module](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) on that `broadcasting` -

```
In [64]: import numexpr as ne

# Re-using mask `m` from previous method
In [65]: ne.evaluate('m*R',{'m':m,'R':to_repeat[:,None]})
Out[65]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 0],
       [3, 3, 0],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5],
       [6, 0, 0]])
```